# Enviroment variable at React Native does not working using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, environment-variables

I added the `react-native-dotenv` library and followed the [guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv) using TypeScript.

I created a `.env` file

```
MARVEL_API = <url>
MARVEL_PUBLIC_KEY = <public-key>
MARVEL_PRIVATE_KEY = <private-key>
```

I added this options at `babel.config.js` file at the `presets`

```
'module:react-native-dotenv',
    {
      moduleName: '@env',
      path: '.env',
      whitelist: ['MARVEL_API', 'MARVEL_PUBLIC_KEY', 'MARVEL_PRIVATE_KEY'],
      safe: false,
      allowUndefined: true,
    },
```

I created a `types` folder with the `end.d.ts` file and I declared the @env as

```
declare module '@env' {
  export const MARVEL_API: string;
  export const MARVEL_PUBLIC_KEY: string;
  export const MARVEL_PRIVATE_KEY: string;
}
```

Whe I saved the files, launched this error:

```
error: index.js: [BABEL] /home/vagner/Documents/www/objective/index.js: Unknown option: .name. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
```

I saw to write `yarn start --reset-cache` but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, I changed the `babel.config.js` file.
The new version is

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
      {
        moduleName: '@env',
        path: '.env',
        blacklist: null,
        whitelist: ['MARVEL_API', 'MARVEL_PUBLIC_KEY', 'MARVEL_PRIVATE_KEY'],
        safe: false,
        allowUndefined: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```